# How to populate a dropdownlist with json data in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, drop-down-menu

I am developing a country state cascading dropdown list... I returned JSON result based on `countryId` but I don't know how to populate/fill it in a new dropdown listbox...

Here is what I am using,

```
function getstate(countryId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Reg_Form.aspx/Getstates",
        data: "{'countryId':" + (countryId) + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        global: false,
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(jsonObj) {
            alert(jsonObj.d);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

And alert gave this,

```
{"Table" : [{"stateid" : "2","statename" : "Tamilnadu"},
            {"stateid" : "3","statename" : "Karnataka"},
            {"stateid" : "4","statename" : "Andaman and Nicobar"},
             {"stateid" : "5","statename" : "Andhra Pradesh"},
             {"stateid" : "6","statename" : "Arunachal Pradesh"}]}
```

And my aspx page has this,

```
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DLCountry" runat="server" CssClass="dropDownListSkin" 
 onchange="return getstate(this.value);">
 </asp:DropDownList>
  </td>
 <td>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DLState" runat="server" CssClass="dropDownListSkin">
   </asp:DropDownList>
 </td>
```

Any suggestion on how to fill `DLState` dropdown...

**EDIT:**

When I inspected through firebug I got the response for my AJAX post,

```
{"d":"{\"Table\" : [{\"stateid\" : \"2\",\"statename\" : \"Tamilnadu\"},{\"stateid\" : \"3\",\"statename\" : \"Karnataka\"},{\"stateid\" : \"4\",\"statename\" : \"Andaman and Nicobar\"},{\"stateid\" : \"5\",\"statename\" : \"Andhra Pradesh\"},{\"stateid\" : \"6\",\"statename\" : \"Arunachal Pradesh\"},{\"stateid\" : \"7\",\"statename\" : \"Assam\"},{\"stateid\" : \"8\",\"statename\" : \"Bihar\"},{\"stateid\" : \"9\",\"statename\" : \"Dadra and N. Haveli\"},{\"stateid\" : \"10\",\"statename\" : \"Daman and Diu\"},{\"stateid\" : \"11\",\"statename\" : \"Delhi\"},{\"stateid\" : \"12\",\"statename\" : \"Goa\"},{\"stateid\" : \"13\",\"statename\" : \"Gujarat\"},{\"stateid\" : \"14\",\"statename\" : \"Haryana\"},{\"stateid\" : \"15\",\"statename\" : \"Himachal Pradesh\"},{\"stateid\" : \"16\",\"statename\" : \"Jammu and Kashmir\"},{\"stateid\" : \"17\",\"statename\" : \"Kerala\"},{\"stateid\" : \"18\",\"statename\" : \"Laccadive Islands\"},{\"stateid\" : \"19\",\"statename\" : \"Madhya Pradesh\"},{\"stateid\" : \"20\",\"statename\" : \"Maharashtra\"},{\"stateid\" : \"21\",\"statename\" : \"Manipur\"},{\"stateid\" : \"22\",\"statename\" : \"Meghalaya\"},{\"stateid\" : \"23\",\"statename\" : \"Mizoram\"},{\"stateid\" : \"24\",\"statename\" : \"Nagaland\"},{\"stateid\" : \"25\",\"statename\" : \"Orissa\"},{\"stateid\" : \"26\",\"statename\" : \"Pondicherry\"},{\"stateid\" : \"27\",\"statename\" : \"Punjab\"},{\"stateid\" : \"28\",\"statename\" : \"Rajasthan\"},{\"stateid\" : \"29\",\"statename\" : \"Sikkim\"},{\"stateid\" : \"30\",\"statename\" : \"Tripura\"},{\"stateid\" : \"31\",\"statename\" : \"Uttar Pradesh\"},{\"stateid\" : \"32\",\"statename\" : \"West Bengal\"}]}"}
```

Comment: see my answer on this one for an example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403441/jquery-ajax-pass-success-data-into-separate-function/2403573#2403573

Comment: Using the onchange event for a dropdownlist (or html select) hasn't worked for me in Firefox and Chrome. I used jQuerys change() instead (http://api.jquery.com/change/).

Comment: @Daniel `$("#<%=DLState.ClientID%>").html(listItems);` this line seems to have error... Any suiggestion..

Comment: Take a look at this, hope this will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952284/jquery-fill-dropdown-with-json-data

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
var listItems= "";
var jsonData = jsonObj.d;
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.Table.length; i++){
      listItems+= "<option value='" + jsonData.Table[i].stateid + "'>" + jsonData.Table[i].statename + "</option>";
    }
    $("#<%=DLState.ClientID%>").html(listItems);
```

**Example**

```
   <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <select id="DLState">
      </select>
    </body>
    </html>

    /*javascript*/
    var jsonList = {"Table" : [{"stateid" : "2","statename" : "Tamilnadu"},
                {"stateid" : "3","statename" : "Karnataka"},
                {"stateid" : "4","statename" : "Andaman and Nicobar"},
                 {"stateid" : "5","statename" : "Andhra Pradesh"},
                 {"stateid" : "6","statename" : "Arunachal Pradesh"}]}

    $(document).ready(function(){
      var listItems= "";
      for (var i = 0; i < jsonList.Table.length; i++){
        listItems+= "<option value='" + jsonList.Table[i].stateid + "'>" + jsonList.Table[i].statename + "</option>";
      }
      $("#DLState").html(listItems);
    });
```

Comment: @jon jsonObj.Table is undefined? Why i get this?

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur, I'm not sure, let me post a working example and maybe that will help.  Try jsonObj.d.Table

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur, no problem.  The example is up, you might want to try replacing jsonObj.Table with jsonObj.d.Table since that is what you are using to generate the jsonObject that is alerted in the code you posted.

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur, No problem, I will update my answer, also I re-posted the example link

Comment: @jon still i get the error `jsonObj.d.Table` is undefined... And some prob with your link i cant see a working example...

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur, I updated my answer again.  I don't know if that will help or why the example link won't work.  I'll just post my example code in my answer.

Comment: @jon see my edited question part... You ll get a fair idea how i receive the data..

Comment: @jon i found the error `$("#<%=DLState.ClientID%>").html(listItems);` since i use asp.net masterpage my id will be different..

Comment: Shouldn't you do a JSON.parse (or eval though not recommended) to get a Javascript object? e.g. var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonObj.d);
I use Douglas Crockfords JSON parser (http://www.json.org/json2.js)

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur, were you able to determine what was wrong with that line?

Answer (score 6):

```
//javascript
//teams.Table does not exist

function OnSuccessJSON(data, status) {
    var teams = eval('(' + data.d + ')');
    var listItems = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
      listItems += "<option value='" + teams[i][0]+ "'>" + teams[i][1] + "</option>";
    }
    $("#<%=ddlTeams.ClientID%>").html(listItems);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To populate ComboBox with JSON, you can consider using the: [jqwidgets combobox](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxcombobox/bindingtojson.htm?classic), too.

Answer (score 0):

try this one its worked for me

```html
$(document).ready(function(e){
        $.ajax({
           url:"fetch",
           processData: false,
           dataType:"json",
           type: 'POST',
           cache: false,
           success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        
                         $.each(data.Table,function(i,tweet){
      $("#list").append('<option value="'+tweet.actor_id+'">'+tweet.first_name+'</option>');
   });}
        });
    });
```