# jquery fill dropdown with json data

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following jQuery code. I am able to get the following data from server `[{"value":"1","label":"xyz"}, {"value":"2","label":"abc"}]`. How do I iterate over this and fill a select box with `id=combobox`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<s:url value="/ajaxMethod.action"/>",
    data:$("#locid").serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.msg);

                //NEED TO ITERATE data.msg AND FILL A DROP DOWN
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Also what is the difference between using `.ajax` and `$.getJSON`.

Comment: What version of jQuery were you using, user373201?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$($.parseJSON(data.msg)).map(function () {
    return $('<option>').val(this.value).text(this.label);
}).appendTo('#combobox');
```

Here's the distinction between `ajax` and `getJSON` (from the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)):

> [getJSON] is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> $.ajax({
>   url: url,
>   dataType: 'json',
>   data: data,
>   success: callback
> });
> ```

---

EDIT: To be clear, part of the problem was that the server's response was returning a json object that looked like this:

```
{
    "msg": '[{"value":"1","label":"xyz"}, {"value":"2","label":"abc"}]'
}
```

...So that `msg` property needed to be parsed manually using `$.parseJSON()`.

Comment: I am getting the following error uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [{"value":"1","label":"xyz - abc"}] at this line $(data.msg).map(function () {

Comment: Ah, of course. `data.msg` is just a string, so it needs to be parsed into a JS object. I've updated the code snippet above to do this, but you should probably fix your server's response to actually return the 'msg' object directly instead of encoding it as a string first.

Comment: @namuol I know this is an old Q/A, and apparently you've gotten a lot of upvotes, but I had the same error when I created a JSON object, parsed & pushed data to a new array. It looked similar to what you added in your edit, except I was using names of people in the `label`, so it was like `Doe, John Q`. It gave me an error on array line 1, field 2, I think it described it as. If I simply did `$.each(dataArray, function () {  $("#combobox").append($("<option></option>").val(this['value']).html(this['label'])); });` it works perfectly. So I'm wondering why `parseJSON` wouldn't work. Name, maybe?

Answer (score 29):

If your data is already in array form, it's really simple using jQuery:

```
 $(data.msg).each(function()
 {
     alert(this.value);
     alert(this.label);

     //this refers to the current item being iterated over

     var option = $('<option />');
     option.attr('value', this.value).text(this.label);

     $('#myDropDown').append(option);
 });
```

`.ajax()` is more flexible than `.getJSON()` - for one, getJson is targeted specifically as a GET request to retrieve json; ajax() can request on any verb to get back any content type (although sometimes that's not useful). getJSON internally calls .ajax().

Comment: Just a recommendation. Create all the html and store it in a variable. When finished add all the html at once using .html() instead. It will speed up the process if you have many options.

Comment: Thanks for the replay and comment. I am getting the following error uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [{"value":"1","label":"xyz - abc"}] at this line $(data.msg).each(function(){

Comment: Im assuming that your data is coming in under the data.msg field. If that is all the data coming back, you simply do `$(data).each`.

Comment: I see that the server is putting a double quotes at the start and end of the json string. what is actually returned is "[{"value":"1","label":"xyz - abc"}]". is there a js/jquery method to convert to json or do i have to use string replace to remove the beginning and ending quotes

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example of code, that attempts to featch AJAX data from `/Ajax/_AjaxGetItemListHelp/` URL. Upon success, it removes all items from dropdown list with `id` = `OfferTransModel_ItemID` and then it fills it with new items based on AJAX call's result:

```
if (productgrpid != 0) {    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Ajax/_AjaxGetItemListHelp/",
        data:{text:"sam",OfferTransModel_ItemGrpid:productgrpid},
        contentType: "application/json",              
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#OfferTransModel_ItemID").empty();

            $.each(data, function () {
                $("#OfferTransModel_ItemID").append($("<option>                                                      
                </option>").val(this['ITEMID']).html(this['ITEMDESC']));
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Returned AJAX result is expected to return data encoded as AJAX array, where each item contains `ITEMID` and `ITEMDESC` elements. For example:

```
{
    {
        "ITEMID":"13",
        "ITEMDESC":"About"
    },
    {
        "ITEMID":"21",
        "ITEMDESC":"Contact"
    }
}
```

The `OfferTransModel_ItemID` listbox is populated with above data and its code should look like:

```
<select id="OfferTransModel_ItemID" name="OfferTransModel[ItemID]">
    <option value="13">About</option>
    <option value="21">Contact</option>
</select>
```

When user selects `About`, form submits `13` as value for this field and `21` when user selects `Contact` and so on.

Fell free to modify above code if your server returns URL in a different format.

Comment: Could you please describe your answer as well as posting code?   As it stands this is not particularly helpful.

Comment: external brackets should be square [, ] as it is an array

Answer (score 0):

In most of the companies they required a common functionality for multiple dropdownlist for all the pages.
Just call the functions or pass your (DropDownID,JsonData,KeyValue,textValue)

```
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

            GetData('DLState',data,'stateid','statename');
        });

        var data = [{"stateid" : "1","statename" : "Mumbai"},
                    {"stateid" : "2","statename" : "Panjab"},
                    {"stateid" : "3","statename" : "Pune"},
                     {"stateid" : "4","statename" : "Nagpur"},
                     {"stateid" : "5","statename" : "kanpur"}];

        var Did=document.getElementById("DLState");

        function GetData(Did,data,valkey,textkey){
          var str= "";
          for (var i = 0; i <data.length ; i++){

            console.log(data);


            str+= "<option value='" + data[i][valkey] + "'>" + data[i][textkey] + "</option>";

          }
          $("#"+Did).append(str);
        };    </script>

</head>
<body>
  <select id="DLState">
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```