# What JSON libraries or frameworks to use for this Ajax requirement

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm working on an exisiting application which is not Spring. It is an application that was built using a home grown MVC framework.
I am able to use jquery and JSON going forward, but not Spring.
I need to build a dropdown that is populated via Ajax.
What libs/frameworks should I look into, and I'm looking for a push in a direction on how to accomplish this.
I'd like to use JSON to get experience with it, and jquery some same reason.
The application uses basic jdbc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do here is create a rest webservice which will return a JSON response with the values in your drop down.

For this you can utilize something like RESTEasy. Take a look at this tutorial on how to create and return JSON values from RESTEasy. It uses RESTEasy to create service and Jackson(See http://jackson.codehaus.org/ AND http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/ for more info)

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/integrate-jackson-with-resteasy/

Once you have service in place you can utilize jQuery to populate the Dropdown . Take a look at below questions on how to do that -

[jQuery: Best practice to populate drop down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815103/jquery-best-practice-to-populate-drop-down)

[jquery fill dropdown with json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952284/jquery-fill-dropdown-with-json-data)

Comment: this info looks great, thx. Are there any reasons NOT to build a ReST service on an application like this, are there any negative consequences?

Comment: No not really. lot of HTML5 based modern websites will use the same pattern of calling Rest services directly from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JQuery, check out the [JQuery ajax method.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)