# Error trying to fill dropdown list with json data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a drop down list and I want to fill it with data from server in the form of json. So i found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952284/jquery-fill-dropdown-with-json-data) and tried to implement it in my code. But i get the following error in chrome.

```
Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8
```

Worse firefox doesn't show any error but the list is not populated at all. Any idea??

I have added the code here

http://jsfiddle.net/alula/77Mtz/

Comment: Could you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code?

Comment: Look at the response using any developer tool in browser. Make sure the data is coming in response.

Comment: You're probably passing an array to a DOM insertion method, like `append(array)`, `html(array)` etc.

Comment: I have added jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/alula/77Mtz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error mean that you are passing an array to your appending function. You see, version before jq1.8 can't have an array as parameter for any append function and throw this error:

```
NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6tW7W/

Upgrading to the newest jQuery (which would be the best move) is your solution :

http://jsfiddle.net/6tW7W/1/

But if you don't want to upgrade, you have to use a loop :

```
$.each(arr, function(i, v){
    $('body').append(v)
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6tW7W/2/

Comment: I am using Jquery-1.7.1, i guess that is latest enough. Right??

Comment: As you can see in the first fiddle, it is using 1.7 and as i said, it doesnt work with version below 1.8, so you need atleast jquery 1.8.