# JQuery fill DropDownList with JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, drop-down-menu

Let's say I have this data returned from a backend service layer:

["2", "3", "7", "14"]

First question. Is this considered valid JSON data? [Json.org](http://www.json.org) says it is, but I cannot find any references to it on Google, SO, etc...

> An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

I want to be able to take these values and add them to an already existing DropDownList object OnLoad using JQuery.

```
$.getJSON("http://www.example.com/path-to-get-data", function(data) { 
  //iterate through each object and add it to the list.
  //ideally, the key and value (string to display to the end user) would be the same.
});
```

I took a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952284/jquery-fill-dropdown-with-json-data), but it has objects, not just an array. Should I use `parseJSON` versus `getJSON`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe this is not valid , valid JSON will be something like {"key:“2”, "key":“3”, "key":“7”, "key":“14”}

Comment: `$.parseJSON('["2", "3", "7", "14"]')` will return an array. Better use getJSON and iterate through each item in the array and add it to your object

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var arr = [ 2, 3, 7, 14];
$.each(arr, function(index, value) {
     ('#myselect').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', index));
});
```

Please also take a look at Mr. C's solution:

```
$('<option></option>').val(item).html(item)
```

His way of manipulating `option`s is new to me, and more elegant.

Comment: It threw "Object doesnot support .append"

Comment: What is your version of jQuery and what is your browser?

Comment: `$.append` is available since very early version. Is your DOM selector (that `$('#myselect')` part) right?

Comment: There's a small typo on line 3 of this answer, that I caught. The `$` in front of `('#myselect).append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', index));` is missing.
This was very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

My solution was based off of [Blaise's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/863637/blaise) idea.

```
//populate the Drop Down List
$.getJSON("http://www.example.com/api/service", function (data) {
     $.each(data, function (index, item) {
         $('#dropDownList').append(
              $('<option></option>').val(item).html(item)
          );
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct JSON, it must be this style:

```
{"0": "2", "1" : "3", "2" : "7", "3" : "14"}
```

You could use that sample to procceed you response:

```
var response = "[2, 3, 7, 14]";
eval("var tmp = " + response); 
console.log(tmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the HiddenField declaration,which is useful to Store The JSON String

```
   <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnBankStatus" runat="server" />
```

This is the Dropdownlist declaration

```
   <select id="optStatus" name="optStatus" runat="server">
        </select>
```

These lines will initialize Hiddenfield value with the sorted list(Assume that list contains the key value pairs in sorted order) which is then serialized using JSON serializer

```
   sl = new SortedList();
   hdnBankStatus.Value = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(sl);
```

These lines will use Elements of JSON String One by one and populate the dropdown with Values.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {  

   var myOptions = $.parseJSON($('#hdnBankStatus').val());
        var mySelect = $('#optStatus');
        $.each(myOptions, function (val, text) {
            mySelect.append(
    $('<option></option>').val(text).html(val)
        );
        });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var arr = [ 2, 3, 7, 14];
 var dropdown = ('#myselect');
 dropdown.empty();
 dropdown.append($('<option value=''>--Please Select--</option>'));
 $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
 dropdown.append($('<option value='+index+'>'+value+'</option>'));
 });`
```

Comment: This should do it

Answer (score -4):

For me, this one worked.

```
$("#ddlCaseType").append("<option>" + txt + "</option>");
```

Comment: $("#ddlCaseType").append("<option>" + txt + "</option>");