# Populating dropdown from JSON string that was returned from a PHP CODE

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am returning a JSON array from my PHP class. Part of the code is as follows:

```
...
echo json_encode($users);
return json_encode($users);

?>
```

The echo statement of the above code is as follows:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "firstname": "Jane",
        "school": "Frohj"
    },
    {
        "ID": "2",
        "firstname": "Mathew",
        "school": "Lebrasky"
    },
    {
        "ID": "3",
        "firstname": "BAHUUU",
        "school": "uni of kansas"
    }
]
```

Now, in my html form i have a DROPDOWN.

```
     <fieldset>
          <legend>Selecting elements</legend>
          <p>
             <label>Select list</label>
             <select id = "myList">
               <option value = "1">I WANT TO DISPLAY USER'S NAME HERE</option>
               <option value = "2">I WANT TO DISPLAY USER'S NAME HERE</option>

             </select>
          </p>
       </fieldset>
```

I want to display users `firstname`s as the fields in the `dropdown box`. The values for this, is obtained from the `JSON` that was passed. Now how do i, retrieve the JSON and populate the dropdown box with `firstname`s of users.

Comment: Get the JSON from Ajax call, then populate the `<select>`. Try and post your code if you have problem.

Comment: lets assume `$data` is an json array. then using foreach loop u will get solution. like that `$data[i][firstname]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952284/jquery-fill-dropdown-with-json-data

Answer (score 0):

You can decode to json result by json_decode($users); this function to convert json result it to array.

with the help of loop you can easily print your options.

Comment: Where should i do this ? The main problem i have is to bring the result set to the HTML. how can i do this ?

Comment: what are you using to get result. ajax.?

Comment: Well, That is the problem i have. I am sending the JSON string, but i don't know how to retrieve the result. Can you help me here

Comment: so you need to parse json. like: success:function(result){ var text = parseJSON(result); } then use a for loop to create a <option></option> tab dynamic in jquery file. and append to this your select box.
Such as : for($i=0; $i<text.length; $i++){ $('<option>'+text[i]['firstname']+'</option>').appendTo('#myList'); }

Comment: with the help of loop you can easily print your options.
parse JSON:
success:function(result){
   var text = parseJSON(result);
   $('#mylsit').empty();
   for(var i=0; i<text.length; i++){
       $('<option>'+text[i].firstname+'</option>').appendTo('#mylist');
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

head of the html page (with php extension)

```
<?php include 'pathTo/find.php' ?>
```

in your script tag:

```
var
  i, len,
  html = ''
  list = <?php echo getUsers(); ?>;

for ( i = 0; len = list.length; i < len ) {
    html += '<option value="'+ i +'">'+ list[i].firstname +'</option>';
}

// $( html ).appendTo( $( '#myList' ) ); <-- jQuery method
document.getElementById( 'myList' ).innerHtml = html;
```

your body tag:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Selecting elements</legend>
    <p>
    <label>Select list</label>
    <select id = "myList">
    </select>
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: The name of my PHP script is find.php. If so how do i retrieve data to the form.

Comment: your script is not on the page?

Comment: No. I have it in a separate class. the name of it is find.php.

Comment: hi @llep, if we could just check out your find.php live, that'll be great. If you have uploaded it on your dev server and if you don't mind sharing it that will be very helpful for us. Thanks!

Comment: @Illep - your page is a php page?

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik The page that contains the dropdown is a HTML (But i could make it .php). The find.php which does all the DB calls is a PHP page.

Comment: @Illep - so you can include your find.php function file in the html page (with .php extenction) ad the call the function that returns the array

Comment: May i know what is <?php echo getUsers(); ?>;

Comment: it's a function defined in your `find.php` file that returns the JSON array of all your users

Answer (score 0):

Think your select should be empty at the beginning, then new options should be appended with javascript.

```
<select id = "myList"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
var data = SOME_SORTOF_GET_JSON(), // get json from your existing function
    select = document.getElementById("myList"),
    newOption;

for(var i = 0, item; item = data[i]; ++i) {
    newOption = new Option(item.firstname, item.id);
    select.add(newOption);
}
</script>
```

Good luck.