# $('#MySelect').append($("<option value='finalv'></option>").val(finalv.Value).text(finalv.Text))

Tags: jquery

```
var result={"clientIds":[{"id":0,"clientId":"check123"},{"id":1,"clientId":"check234"}]};
$.each(result, function (key, data) {
    $.each(data, function (index1, valindex) {
        $.each(valindex,function(finalk,finalv) {
            alert("Final Key::::"+finalk+"Final Value::::"+finalv);
            $('#MySelect').append($("<option value='finalv'></option>").val(finalv.Value).text(finalv.Text));
            //  alert("Working"); 
        });
    });
 });
```

I have code like this. In last `each` loop I get values 0,check123,1,check234

The above values I want to put in a dropdown

My code is:

```
$('#MySelect').append($("<option></option>").val(finalv.Value).text(finalv.Text))
```

When I execute the code, field's name is not displayed in dropdown. I want value names as each option. How can I do this?

Comment: It's not a good idea to put code into question's header, you know...

Comment: Please, consider to use a **descriptive title**, among others.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dxub90y5/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to fill a dropdown with JSON data,you need to parse it first.Here is a [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952284/jquery-fill-dropdown-with-json-data) that shows the same.

You need to separate the Key-Value pair from the JSON object, put it in an option tag and append the option tag to dropdown.

I suggest you to try this,

```
$.each(result, function (key, data) {
    $.each(data, function (index1, valindex) {
        $($.parseJSON(valindex)).map(function () {
            return $('<option>').val(this.value).text(this.label);
        }).appendTo('#MySelect');
        //  alert("Working"); 
    });
});
```