# Through ajax not able to fill HTML dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {  
         $.ajax({
             url: '/Umbraco/api/RegisterUser/GetCountry',
            type: 'GET', // You can use GET
            data: '{}',
            dataType: "json",
            context: this,                
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);

                $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                    $('#ddcountry').append(
                        $("<option></option>")
                          .attr("value", item.Country_name)
                          .text(item.Country_name)
                    );
                });

                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (request) {
                alert("error");                   
            }
        });  
});
```

My code return on URL path is

```
 [HttpGet]
 public string GetCountry()
 {
    String daresult = null;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt1=new DataTable();
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT countryid,country_name FROM country_master", UmbracoConnectionString))
    {
        da.Fill(dt1);
    }

            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>(10);
            Dictionary<string, object> row;

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt1.Rows)
            {
                DataRow[] dr1 = dt1.Select("countryid=" + dr["countryid"]);
                if (dr1.Count() > 0)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt1.Columns)
                    {
                        if (col.ColumnName == "country_name")
                            {
                                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);                                   
                            }                                

                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
            return serializer.Serialize(rows);
        }
```

My HTML code is below where i had inserted some of the data manually

```
  Country:<select id="ddcountry">
    </select>
```

But by doing all this things **how should I fill my dropdown with retriving data as data shown in below image

On alert of data i am getting data as below

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the request in the console? The URL looks odd.

Comment: ohk on removing static I am able to get success, now how should i feel my dropdown

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think he is using MVC

Comment: @Xtremcool http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery

Comment: @Xtremcool Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637694/how-to-populate-a-dropdownlist-with-json-data-in-jquery

Comment: @JonathanNewton Yep, but my point was that he seems to have two actions in the URL: `RegisterUser` and `GetCountry`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ah spot on!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan its an actual path not an issue in that, on succes i am getting data as {"Table1":[1,"abc"],[2,"abc1"],[3,"abc2",null]} but not able to fill the dropdown

Comment: Any one help please?

Comment: What's the output of `/Umbraco/api/RegisterUser/GetCountry` looks like? It may not be well formatted JSON object.

Comment: @sємsєм updated the question, I am receiving data as shown in image

Comment: Any how now i am able to get different type of record and i want to show countryname only, now any help?

Comment: @sємsєм I am using Umbraco, in that i am using HTML control

Comment: @Xtremcool It is very nice to find a solution for your question, what I have meant by the output, is the output printed in the browser not the alert message. i.e visiting `yoursite.com/Umbraco/api/RegisterUser/GetCountry`. However, the string shown in the alert screen shot, is not correct JSON object. Any JSON object should start with curly braces.

Comment: @sємsєм actually at different places ajax are being called so i m just following same syntax, I will take care now on wards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, It will solve your issue:

First, You need to convert your JSON String to JSON Array and Then Iterate it to dynamically create `options` for your `select` dropdown.

```
var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

$.each(res , function (key, item) {
    $('#ddcountry').append(
        $("<option></option>")
          .attr("value", item.country_name)
          .text(item.country_name)
    );
});
```

Comment: and instead of response i have to put data, and other all things would be saame?

Comment: well i have tried and its showing only old record like vovo, saab and all that , not the country name

Comment: @Xtremcool There is problem with your JSON data. I have created a fiddle to demonstrate the same. https://jsfiddle.net/gschambial/25ndL3pv/2/ Can you check and confirm?

Comment: @Xtremcool i have updated my answer and fiddle as well. You can check. I guess it will work for you.

Comment: @gschanbial i have also updated my question from your code please review my json data and succes code, its showing blank over there

Comment: You have used `item.id`, instead you should use `item.country_name`. Have you checked the fiddle?

Comment: @Xtremcool on `alert`, JSON data is coming in right format. I can see from screenshot.

Comment: Yes also see success part there also i had implement your fiddle code, but my dropdown is showing blank

Comment: `ddcountry` empty select dropdown is present in your HTML code before executing AJAX call or you need to create it dynamically ? @Xtremcool

Comment: @Xtremcool Remove `alert` statements from your code and run once.

Comment: yes ddcountry empty select dropdown is present in my HTML code before exceuting ajax call

Comment: @Xtremcool Have you tried after removing `alert` statmements?

Comment: I have tried removing alert statement still not working

Comment: @Xtremcool can you check developer console? if you are getting any errors?

Comment: error like
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://catcher.gourmetads.com/pub.php?pid=859. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:59462' is therefore not allowed access.

but i dont think so it is related to this

Comment: 1 more error Uncaught TypeError: $R(...).tiles is not a function
but this come before ajax runs

Comment: @Xtremcool Is your `document.ready` code at bottom of the page or in the `head` section?

Comment: its is on head section

Comment: @Xtremcool Ohh, i see. Just move it to the bottom of your page, before `body` section ends. It will work.

Comment: done still not working, but we can make it write any where i think so, 1 more thing I am using umbraco but in that case i am calling other function and they totally are working well. I have issue in this case only, yesterday i had tried sending data through ajax and it is also working well. U can also see my updated code on which i am trying

Comment: @Xtremcool actually, it will not work if you place it at the head section because, your page at that stage is not rendered completely. Therefore, `ddcountry` dropdown will not be visible inside your AJAX success callback. Though, i will check yiur update.

Comment: @Xtremcool I think data is a json string not json object in your example. So, can you just add `data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);` before creating `select`. It will convert your JSON string into JSON Object. I have updated the answer also. Check and Confirm.

Comment: u mean    var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    $.each(res, function (key, item) {
            $('#ddcountry').append(
                            $("<option></option>")
                              .attr("value", item.Country_name)
                              .text(item.Country_name)
                        );
                    });

still not working

Comment: @Xtremcool You are writing `Country_name` here? Character `C` is not capital in your JSON, change it to `item.country_name` with `c` small character.

Comment: Yes now its working fine thanks,
please update your answer so that i make it done

Comment: @Xtremcool My pleasure. I have update the answer. You can mark it as done.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in the success section:

```
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    $('#yourDiv').find('#yourSelect')
                    .append($('<option>', { value: item['yourID'], 
                                           text: item['yourText'] }));
                });
```

Also try doing this in your class:

```
//daresult = DataSetToJSON(ds);
return Json(daresult);
```

Comment: I had tried doing success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        $('#ddcountry').append($('<option>', { value: item['countryid'], text: item['country_name'] }));
                    });
                    alert("success");
                },

and is not working

Comment: Have you set a break point to see that you are actually getting data back from the call?  Is the URL correct?

Comment: on doing   alert(data); in success i am getting proper data

Comment: Set a break point on your call to public string GetCountry() as see that you are reaching the server.

Comment: on doing alert(data); in success i am getting proper data {"Table1":[1,"abc"],[2,"abc1"],[3,"abc2",null]}

Comment: JSON format what ever you are getting not correct ... 
 correct format is.. {
   "Table1": {[1, "abc"],
   [2, "abc1"],
   [3, "abc2", null]}
 }

Comment: Yes I think you should let .NET do the work.  See my updated answer.

Comment: But the data I am receiving is correct earlier my code retrieving json format was not correct so i had updated the code and now mu updated json format is like

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Umbraco/api/RegisterUser/GetCountry',
        type: 'GET', // You can use GET
        data: '{}',
        dataType: "json",
        context: this,                
        success: function (data) {
            var options = "";
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                options += '<option value="'+item.id+'">'+item.label+'</option>';
            });
            $('#ddcountry').append(options);
        },
        error: function (request) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Tried putting this, data is filling as undefined

Comment: I have tried putting this as   options += '<option value="' + item.countryid + '">' + item.country_name + '</option>';
still undefined is coming

Comment: on doing alert(data); in success i am getting data as {"Table1":[1,"abc"],[2,"abc1"],[3,"abc2",null]}

Comment: what is your data return from ajax request

Comment: from code in am retriving country id an country_name and on converting it to JavaScriptSerializer i am getting data as {"Table1":[1,"abc"],[2,"abc1"],[3,"abc2",null]}