# Unable to load Json data to dropdown

Tags: jquery

Unable to load DPURL data in dropdown "Select".

```
var DPURL = "http://172.16.225.201/OoredooRestApi/ExchangeName/CabinetExchangeName";

$.getJSON(DPURL, function(data) {

    var sel = document.getElementById("Select");
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.innerHTML = data[i]['RLU'];
        opt.value = data[i]['RLU'];
        sel.appendChild(opt);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and provide more information, what error are you getting, other details?

Answer (score 0):

you can check with below link and you will find the solution:

[Unable to load Json data to dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637694/how-to-populate-a-dropdownlist-with-json-data-in-jquery)