# My ASP.NET MVC AJAX request is opening my Content() in a new window

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering whether you guys could help me figure out what I'm missing that is making my AJAX request return my Content in a new window. I was trying to follow the post [Using Ajax.BeginForm with ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410055/using-ajax-beginform-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor) like a recipe book and apparently I'm missing something.

**C:**

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddOrganization ( string newOrgName )
    {

        PortalData PD = new PortalData();

        if ((from thisorg in PD.orgs where thisorg.orgname == newOrgName select thisorg).Count() > 0)
        {
            return Content("Organization name '" + newOrgName + " 'already exists in database!", "text/html");               
        } // error if that organization exists

        PD.orgs.InsertOnSubmit(new Organization { orgname = newOrgName });

        try
        {
            PD.SubmitChanges();
        } // try submitting to db
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Content(e.Message, "text/html");
        }

        // if made it here, everything is good
        return Content(newOrgName + " successfully added to database!", "text/html");
    }
```

**M:**

```
    </script>
    <h3>Or Add New Organization</h3>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddOrganization", "FileUpload", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "new-org-output-msg" }))
    {
        <input type="text" name="newOrgName" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    }
    <p><i id="new-org-output-msg"></i></p>
```

Submitting, say, `"StackOverflow"` opens up a page with the source code nothing more than

```
Stack Overflow successfully added to database!
```

whereas my intention was my for that piece of text to be inside

```
<i id="new-org-output-msg"></i>
```

Comment: Are you including jQuery and the Unobtrusive Ajax scripts? Those are required for this to work properly.

Comment: You need to include the `jquery-{version}.js` and `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` files (otherwise `Ajax.BeginForm()` acts as a normal form)

Answer (score 0):

This is what is telling it to open the content in a new window:

```
 Content(newOrgName + " successfully added to database!", "text/html");
```

Why not just return the string to the Ajax call and in the ajax success handler, display the message as it should appear.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "return the string to the Ajax call"? (Sorry, I'm new to this stuff)

Comment: return newOrgName + " successfully added to database!";

Comment: Then on the ajax side you can do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403441/jquery-ajax-pass-success-data-into-separate-function