# Pass value to variable using ajax in non-asynchronised way

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently working on a website function

The problem is I would like to put an ajax jquery call in a function and meanwhile pass the value from response.

To archive that I used non-asynchronous ajax call, but when I tried to display the value on the html it only display for a really short time.(like a flash of time)
The coding is shown here below

```
<div id="id01"></div>

<script>
var testing = "false";
 var something;

function create(callback){

$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'json_test.php',
    data: "name="+testing,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: callback,
    async: false})
;}
    var callback = function(data, textStatus, xhr){
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = data;
    }
```

This is my first time asking a question here, but thanks to everyone in advance to help my problem.

Comment: I don't understand why you use sync request here. the idea is to execute an ajax request and wait for a response (in the success callback) and then you can use jQuery command to put the value.

Comment: @RanHassid I used sync request because it seems that the function will not wait for the response to comeback. I put an alert inside the callback function and it did not alert.

Comment: Hi, and you tried to see if you have an issue on the server side (php side) maybe? can you please post your php code ?

Comment: _"put an alert inside the callback function and it did not alert"_ Is `callback` passed to `create` when called ?

Comment: The php only echos back a string and it did echos back the string successfully. I don't think it is the problem at all but here it is:

     <?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$some = false;
$some = $_GET["name"];
$some = json_decode($some);

if($some)
 $outp = '"Say Hi"';
else
 $outp = '"Say No"';

echo $outp;

Comment: ok so like @guest271314 ask , did you pass the callback to the create method ?  
something like 
create(function(data){
});

Comment: What is expected result of `$some = json_decode($some)` ? Not appear that `json` type response is returned from `php` at `if($some) $outp = '"Say Hi"'; else $outp = '"Say No"'; echo $outp;` ? Try setting `dataType` to `"text"`

Comment: @guest271314 yes it is. I am not sure what it does but I take reference from this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403441/jquery-ajax-pass-success-data-into-separate-function

Comment: @guest271314 Appeared that the response changed from a string to a string with quotation mark. Probably because the php side echo ' "string" ';
and the problem has not yet solved. The innerHTML of id01 is still showing that response for a really short period and then it disappear again
I tried to store the responsed data to a global variable before but the same thing happens.

Comment: Is `callback` passed to `create` , e.g., `create(callback)` ?

Comment: @guest271314 the 
     $some 
is supposed to be a boolean, which worked when I changed the passing value in the html page.

Comment: @guest271314 Yes the callback is passed to the create function

Comment: Tried adjusting `async` to `true` ? Do any events call `create` ?

Comment: @guest271314 I tried to turn async to true but nothing occurs (that part I put the alert inside call back and nothing happens) And there is no other events calling create so far. And I might forgot to mention, create() is called by a button. Not sure if it is important though.

Comment: _"And I might forgot to mention, create() is called by a button. Not sure if it is important though."_ Yes, can include `html` , `js` which calls `create` at Question ?

Comment: <p id="startstop"><form id="startGame" onsubmit ="create(callback)">
  Room Code:
  <input type="text" id="roomCode" value="Put your room code here">  <input type="submit" value="Start Game!">
</form></p>
       
 The form is now doing nothing with the values inside. It will after I solved this problem.

Comment: _"tried to display the value on the html it only display for a really short time.(like a flash of time)"_ `<form id="startGame" onsubmit ="create(callback)">` reloading document at `submit` event ?

Comment: Oh silly me. You might have the point...I gonna check further into that. Great thanks anyway.

Comment: @guest271314 I think I solved the problem. I couldn't have done it without your help ^^ Thanks again for the reload tip.