# Posting request from javascript in AJAX to C# methods, no returning value, ASP.NET, MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Environment:

```
<package id="jQuery" version="3.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

I tried to post a request from one of my javascript files to my methods in C# file. So far the request returns 200 OK, but the response content is empty, using `console.log(response)` it shows `undefined`. Is it the problem with my requesting url or I didn't make my C# function right? Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Here's my Javascript:

```
<script>
    console.log("hello_List!")
    function getSearch() {
        console.log($("#query").val())
        console.log(typeof($("#query").val()))
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./Search",
            data:  $("#query").val(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }

    function OnSuccess(response) {
        alert("Success!");
        console.log(response);
    }
</script>
```

Here is my C# function, which is in the same folder as my javascript file:

```
    public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
            [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
            public JsonResult Search(string query)
            {
                List<EntityModels.AspNetUser> users = new List<EntityModels.AspNetUser>();
                users = db.AspNetUsers.Where(x => x.Email.StartsWith(query)).ToList();
                List<SelectListItem> userObjs = new List<SelectListItem>();

                foreach (var user in users)
                {
                    var userObj = new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = user.Id.ToString(),
                        Text = user.Email
                    };

                    userObjs.Add(userObj);
                }

                return new JsonResult()
                {
                    Data = userObjs,
                    JsonRequestBehavior = System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                };
            }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403441/jquery-ajax-pass-success-data-into-separate-function)

Comment: `data:  $("#query").val(),` looks wrong

Comment: Thanks, @epascarello, I tried to pass some static string through the function like data: "ye"   But still it returns an empty string, so I guess it is how it handles the string gets wrong?

Comment: Did you debug the serverside code or look at what is returned in the network panel?

Comment: @Qiaofei what are you passing in `data` property? Can u give some example here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for help! I've found the solution now, it's the data.
Instead of simply input a string, json with index and value work in this case.
So I changed the data attribute to:

```
data: { query: $("#query").val() },
```

This solved the problem

Comment: its always recommended to use `JSON.stringify` method on top of data property for best results. E.g you should use `JSON.stringify(data: { query: $("#query").val() });` for more robust approach.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", 
 url: "./Search", 
data: $.("#query").val(), 
dataType: "json", 
success: function(response){
//your success method code
```

goes here
    }
     ,failure: function (response)    { alert(response.d); } });

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I tried your code, still, it returns an empty list. Is there anything wrong with how I passed the parameter to the C# function? Thanks a lot!